# calling post request but get request calling on network angular 5

Tags: angular

trying to do post request but it's calling get method, please help me out

server.service.ts file

```
export class ServerService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookieService: CookieService) { }

    postData(url, payload) {
        debugger
        const headers = new HttpHeaders(
            { 'Authorization': this.cookieService.get('token') }
        );
        let apiURL = 'http://192.168.100.4:8000' + url;
        let api = null;
        return this.http.post(apiURL, payload,
            { headers: headers });
    }
}
```

otp.component.ts

```
otpPost(){
      var self = this;
      let otpURL = '/verifyotp';
      let payload = {"otp": self.signUpForm.controls.otp.value};
      self.serverService.postData(otpURL, payload)
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            console.log(data);
          },
          (err) => console.log(err)
        )
    }
```

network call[image]

Postman app response
[image]

Headers
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but you are missing the `bearer` string that precedes the token within your headers.

Answer (score 0):

`Status Code: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED` definitely means that you are trying to do a post on an existing API endpoint that isn't a `POST`. I suggest verifying the HTTP Protocol that is offered on the endpoint.

Comment: to do post call this.http.post(url, payload, {headers: headers}) I am doing only as per doc https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Did you write the Back End API? I am assuming you're serving it from Gunicorn

Comment: Yes it's Gunicorn Python but I didn't wrote Back End API my friend working on back end

Comment: I would say try hitting the endpoint with Postman app and see if you successfully perform a `Post`. If yes, then the endpoint is correct and the issue lies between Gunicorn and Angular. But I suspect the endpoint isn't!

Comment: Sounds like the token you're using has expired.

Comment: token is working fine for other API call, OTP expiration time is after 10 mins and i called within 10 mins only

Comment: Well if you're getting this error and other API endpoints are fine, then it sounds as though there are issues with the supposed `POST` endpoint. Have your friend assist you with the API on solving your Postman issue.

Comment: I guess there is problem with API but my call should be POST only why it's showing GET req

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of headers used on Postman please? Resolve the Postman issue, then you can make other determinations as to why Angular isn't working properly.

Comment: It's midnight in India now, tomorrow I'll tell him to resolve the postman issue

Comment: `Authorization:` should be `bearer eyj...` not `token eyj...` since it looks like you're using a JWT

Comment: got solution API url need one more slash otpURL = '/verifyotp/'